# The image of the topological embedding is locally closed

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I encountered the following statement in a book about the Lie groups.

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ and $N$ be topological manifolds and let $\psi\colon N\to M$ be a topological embedding. Then $\psi(N)$ is locally closed in $M$. In other words, for every $y\in\psi(N)$ there is a neghbourhood $W$ of $y$ in $M$ such that $\psi(N)\cap W$ is closed in $W$.

This seems to be just a simple fact from topology, but I cannot figure out how to proceed.

Firstly, since $M$ is a topological manifold, then for $x=\psi^{-1}(y)$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $N$ and homeomorphism $\varphi\colon U\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the map $\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\psi(U)$ is also a homeomorphism. My guess would be that now  we can take the open set $W$ in $M$ such that $\psi(U)=W\cap \psi(N)$ (note that $\psi(U)$ is open in the induced topology on $\psi(N)$) and prove that $\psi(N)\cap W$ is closed in $W$ but I don't understand how to do it.

Perhaps we can use $\varphi^{-1}(B_{\varepsilon}(0))$ instead of $U$ and try to prove that $(\psi\circ\varphi^{-1})(\overline{B_{\varepsilon}(0)})$ is the closure of $(\psi\circ\varphi^{-1})(B_{\varepsilon}(0))$ in $M$, but I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your statement of the Proposition, what is $U$?

Comment: In case you are unaware of how to connect your definition of locally closed to the one used at the duplicate: if $\psi(N)$ is open as a subset of its closure, then you can just take $W$ to be such that $\overline{\psi(N)}\cap W=\psi(N)$.